# Problemas al enviar correo con java

Tags: java, email

Tengo el siguiente código en java para enviar correo electrónico. El problema es que donde lo quiero implementar se encuentra un firewall que bloquea la conexión. ¿Hay alguna de forma de evitar eso?

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    Properties propiedad = new Properties();
    propiedad.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    propiedad.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    propiedad.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    propiedad.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
```

este es el error

> javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com; nested exception is: java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.com

Comment: este es el error javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.com

Comment: Si tienes un firewall que bloquea la petición no vas a poder hacer nada a no ser que en dicho firewall permitas las conexiones.

Comment: alexval si el firewall bloquea la peticion

Comment: hola o se puede mandar un txt a un dropbox?

Comment: Ni idea, lo siento.

Comment: Primero debes validar que el Firewall permita salidas del equipo donde se va a realizar el envió con destino al smtp.gmail.com con puerto 587, si configuras eso en el Firewall te debería funcionar, por otro lado si no lo permite puedes usar un proxy donde la configuración de proxy que realices permita un acceso a Internet libre.